# Trying to pull all values out of a multidimensional (recursive) array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a single array that contains all of the values of an existing multidimensional array.  This is what I have so far:

```
function MaxArray($arr) {

    foreach ($arr as $value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {
            MaxArray($value);
        } else {
            $array[] = $value;
        }
    }
    print_r($array);

}

$arr = array(array(141,151,161), 2, 3, array(101, 202, array(303,404, array(1,2))));

MaxArray($arr);
```

When I execute this code, I get this response from the print_r function...

```
Array ( [0] => 141 [1] => 151 [2] => 161 ) Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 303 [1] => 404 ) Array ( [0] => 101 [1] => 202 ) Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )
```

As you can see, this is not what I am looking for and I can't figure out how to combine all of the values in the multidimensional array into a single array.  Can anyone please point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're trying to do is often called 'array flattening', so `ArrayFlatten` is probably a better name for a function than `MaxArray` (since the latter sounds like it'll return the highest value in the array, which [`max`](http://php.net/max) does very well). `ArrayFlatten` could be written like this:

```
function ArrayFlatten($array, $return) {
  for ($x = 0; $x < count($array); $x++) {
    if(is_array($array[$x])) {
      $return = ArrayFlatten($array[$x], $return);
    }
    else {
      if($array[$x]) {
        $return[] = $array[$x];
      }
    }
  }

  return $return;
}
```

And used like this:

```
$myarray = array('a','b',array(array(array('x'),'y','z')),array(array('p')));    
$res = ArrayFlatten($myarray,array());
```

To get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => x
    [3] => y
    [4] => z
    [5] => p
)
```

From [here](http://davidwalsh.name/flatten-nested-arrays-php).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, your function worked great except it is showing a bunch of notice errors that look like this...

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /Users/Devin/Sites/mywebapp/query.php on line 16

Any idea what is causing those errors?

Comment: The `$x <= count($array)` test should be `$x < count($array)`. Alternatively, use a foreach loop, which will work with non-integer indices. You can then adapt the function to preserve string keys (though you'll need to decide what to do about string-key collisions).

Comment: @Dominic: make $return pass-by-reference for efficiency's sake. You can also set a default value of `array()` for `$return` to simplify usage.

Answer (score 0):

$array is recreated and printed in every execution of MaxArray(). You need to build it up over all recursive executions. I think the best way to do it is to have the MaxArray() function return that array rather than print it out. ... and as I type this, Dominic Rodger has just done it for you!

Answer (score 0):

The function should take a reference to the result array, which will never change.

```
function flatten($cur, & $result) { ... flatten($x, $result); ... }
```

Here is an example: http://davidwalsh.name/flatten-nested-arrays-php

Answer (score 0):

Here's another variant that illustrates use of `foreach` and preserving (some) string keys.

```
function array_flatten($array) {
    $rslt = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $rslt = array_merge($rslt, array_flatten($val));
        } elseif (is_int($key)) {
            $rslt[] = $val;
        } else {
            // for string keys, earlier values are overwritten with later ones
            $rslt[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $rslt;
}
```

For different collision behavior, change the `$rslt[$key] = $val;` line.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to output the max value of a recursive array, use this

```
function MaxArray($arr) {
  $max = 0;
  foreach($arr as $a)
  {
   if(is_array($a)) {
     $max = MaxArray($a);
   } else if($a > $max){
     $max = $a;
   }
 }
 return $max;
}
```